# A subset of positive integers closed under addition with gcd =1 must have all but a finite number of the non negative integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have done no number theory. With that in mind, please give me a proof for the statement below:

$(A\subseteq\Bbb Z^+) \land(x\in A \land y\in A\implies x+y\in A)\land (gcd(A)=1) \implies \exists n_0\in \Bbb Z^+,\forall n\in\Bbb Z^+,n\ge n_0(n \in A) $

I have seen other proofs like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1604366/prove-a-set-of-nonnegative-integers-with-greatest-common-divisor-1-and-closed-un)

and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153554/a-property-of-additive-subsets-of-mathbbz-with-gcd-1?rq=1)

which I wasn't able to follow. Whatever terms you're using here please define them. Please don't presuppose of me any knowledge of number theory.

Comment: An old Q is to show that if $a,b$ are co-prime unequal  members of  $\Bbb Z^+$ then  for any $n\in \Bbb Z$ with $n\geq ab-a-b+1$  there exist $x,y\in \Bbb Z^+ \cup \{0\}$ such that $ax+by=n.$..... So if $ab+1\leq n'\in \Bbb Z^+$  let $x'=x+1$ and $y'=y+1$ , where $ax+by=n'-p-q$, and we have $n'=ax'+by'.$

Comment: What are p and q here?

Comment: $p$ and $q$ should have been $a$ and $b$.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not able to connect the dots. Could you please provide a proof of the old Q and then explain to me how the old Q's result leads to the result in the question?